# Dependencies not copied to bin folder

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have created a new web site using Visual Studio 2017.  The target framework for this site is NetCoreApp 1.1.  As this is an MVC project, it references a number of Microsoft and third-party dlls from Nuget.  I also have a data project that I created as a library.  It is Netstandard1.6.  When I build the solution, none of the dlls from the Nuget packages are copied to the bin folder.  This causes the app to crash with a FileNotFound exception when attempting to debug it.  The project references are being copied correctly, so it appears to only be a problem with Nuget packages.  As a workaround, I can publish the project and copy that output to the bin folder, but I shouldn't have to do that, should I?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

.NET Core uses the generated `.deps.json` file in the output to resolve assemblies, so it avoids copying the files unnecessarily during the build.

However if some assemblies try to look for other assemblies in the output directory or the files referenced in the `deps.json` file cannot be accessed (e.g. testing build output in IIS), you can add this to a `<PropertyGroup>` element in your csproj file to cause the NuGet assemblies to be copied to the output directory:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: @pantonis the description already describes adding it to a PropertyGroup.

Comment: @MartinUllrich works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

This 'CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies' doesn't do anything on my end. The only way I found to get the content of the 'runtime' folder in my output is to use 'Publish'. This is not a solution to locally debug an application.

Edit :
Adding the Runtime IDentifiers to the project file seems to do it for me.
Also, .NET Core 3.0 fixes the issue but it is only in Preview.

Comment: This does not seem like an answer to OP's question

Comment: Can't comment :) I just wanted to say that `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` is broken basically.